# One column (boolean) defines the other (boolean) but not vice versa

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

Let's assume life is not only existent on earth but there are also other living things in the universe. I have a table that shows all kinds of species of the whole world

```
+----+---------------+-------+-------+
| id | name          | green | forgn |
+----+---------------+-------+-------|
|  1 | belgian horse | false | false |
|  2 | polar bear    | false | false |
|  3 | andromeda dog | true  | true  |
|  4 | cosmos cat    | true  | true  |
|  5 | amazon parrot | true  | false |
...
```

We also know that every extraterrestrial being (in this case `andromeda dog` and `cosmos cat`) has a green color. So I'd like to define a constraint that *if `forgn` is true, `green` must also be true*, but it doesn't apply the other way around, so for example an `amazon parrot` is a green animal still it doesn't live outside the earth.

I think I should do it somehow using [CHECK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html) but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: Do you want to write a query or enforce some rules on the data that can be in your table?

Comment: @SuperMario the latter. I'm thinking of an ALTER TABLE statement. If there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use boolean type then true > false 
 
In this case you can use

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
..........
CHECK (green >= forgn)
)
```

Comment: A very smart solution, I didn't think of that. I tested and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a slightly different check on the table.

```
test=# \d test_stackoverflow;
Table "public.test_stackoverflow"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 animal | text    |
 p1     | boolean | not null
 p2     | boolean | not null
Check constraints:
    "test_stackoverflow_check" CHECK (p2 AND p1 = p2 OR p2 = false)

test=#
insert into public.test_stackoverflow values ('cat', true, true );
INSERT 0 1
test=#
insert into public.test_stackoverflow values ('dog', true, false );
INSERT 0 1
test=#
insert into public.test_stackoverflow values ('parrot', false, true );
ERROR:  new row for relation "test_stackoverflow" violates check constraint "test_stackoverflow_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (parrot, f, t).
test=#
```

Answer (score 0):

You might add an Insert/update trigger on your table. 
Each time when a value for the column is `forgn` is changed, update the `green` column inside the trigger.